# Docker Apline - Can't open lib '/app/informix/connect410FC12/lib/cli/libifcli.so' file not found

Tags: docker, informix, alpine-linux

I am implementing a Go service which connects to Informix DB with base image as Apline. I have installed below for the drivers

```
gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev tar curl unixodbc
```

While executing I am getting below error

> SQLDriverConnect: {01000} [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/app/informix/connect410FC12/lib/cli/libifcli.so' : file not
> found

When CLI'd to Docker I could see the file in the path mentioned

[image]

Need help in overcoming this.

Comment: Does that shared library have other C shared-library dependencies that might not be present in your image, or in the Alpine base?  If you need a large number of supporting libraries, would a Debian or Ubuntu base image (with a more standard GNU libc) work better?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: When I run "ldd libifcli.so" on a 4.10.FC14 install of Informix CSDK it reports that libifgls.so and libifglx.so were not found. Both of these libraries exist in the $INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql directory, which should also exist in your installation. If so, then the problem is likely related to LD_LIBRARY_PATH not being set to include both of these directories.

Comment: @SimonRiddle, I have "esql" folder in LD_LIBRARY_PATH too. Still facing the same issue

Comment: The question mentions "implementing a Go service" which I take to mean the implementation of a service using the Go language that runs as a systemd service. If that's the case then I would verify that the setting for LD_LIBRARY_PATH from within that service is as expected, perhaps by adding the "env" and "ldd $INFORMIXDIR/lib/libifcli.so" commands to the script that is used to start the service (redirecting the output of those commands to a suitable file).